# Hosting WCF Service in Azure and Consuming Them

Tags: wcf, azure

I have some unclear questions about hosting a WCF service in Azure: I will have only a web service (no web pages), just a web service through with more clients will be able to save data to SQL Azure.

I created the web service on my local machine.

1. hosting the service: What is the best way to host it, keeping in mind that there are no web pages? I thought about hosting it in a worker role and using Queues storage for storing the requests from clients ... is this fine? Is it maybe better using a WCF hosting role for the service, queues storage to store the work and the worker role that will pull out tasks from queue (first in - first out) ..? What do you recommend guys?
2. do you have guys any sample code how to serialize an object and send it to the WCF service and then deserialize it? I am having some issues with this, can't get it work.
3. I am getting stuck with the security of this service using certificates.

I have posted another question here: [Best Practices WCF Service - Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217125/best-practices-wcf-service-windows-azure) but I am quite at the beginning with Azure.

Comment: So there will be hosted just the WCF service where clients can connect and save data to SQL azure in a secure way (certificates), basically there will be quite much background work ... so for this I thought about hosting it in a worker role will be better ... what about hosting it and having quite much background work ... will this affect performances?

Comment: Hi again... I went over a post: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981690/windows-azure-wcf-security>, what do you think about this method of authentication, instead of using SSL certificates? What is the best way of authenticate the client? Thanks again!

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Too many questions in one post here and there are problems with all of them: #1 is a "what is the best <x> with multiple sub questions" - have you done any research? #2 is a code request which we don't do here. Show us what you tried. #3 Is vague, you don't say what you're getting stuck on. We prefer specific answerable questions on our sites.

Answer (score 2):

Unless

1. You expect to get VERY heavy traffic on your service or each message to be processed might take a long time and the clients are OK to use async service calls
2. You have particularly strict security concerns and need to use a [gatekeeper pattern](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gatekeeper%20pattern%20azure&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/E/73E4EE93-559F-4D0F-A6FC-7FEC5F1542D1/SecurityBestPracticesWindowsAzureApps.docx&ei=zIQ1T9WyCqfP0QWQprmVAg&usg=AFQjCNHKgGfzfQtS37g04WIn6O4H6C8z5g&sig2=9PFIXV_K4DaFxwuezVU0yQ)

I would use a web role for your service. This should give you very good and simple scalability - just by adding more role instances.

The pattern of offloading service processing to a background worker role via a queue is mainly for load levelling in very high traffic or computationally expensive services or to enforce very strict access control.

For security, certificates are a relatively complex, especially if you have to come up with a way of distributing them to the clients. On Azure, it might make more sense to use the Azure Access Control Service (ACS) this allows you to do federated security with various identity providers such as Live ID, Google, Yahoo! and Facebook. If your clients are in a Windows enterprise type environment, then they could federate with their on premise Active Directory. The best way really depends on your specific scenario. A good starting point for the ACS is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429784.aspx

The details of how you use the ACS depends on the nature of your service. If it is a SOAP service (e.g. wsHttpBinding or basicHttpBinding in WCF) I would use WIF. This is very well supported and very simple to program. Again, there are lots of tutorials on how to do this. Google will be your friend. If you are making a REST service, it is a little bit more complicated to develop, but still very doable.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4067.aspx

As for serialising objects to send to WCF services, if you are using .Net on the client side, this is all handled for you by the WCF client stack. There are lots of tutorials, samples, books and training courses for this on the web. Try this one as a starter on Azure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651130.aspx

The choice of SOAP or REST again depends on your scenario

- REST will give you wider support for different clients such as mobile devices etc.
- SOAP gives you more options for security and a few more sophisticated behaviours, but will limit your clients more than REST

REST is very popular these days, but it really depends on your needs. SOAP still fits for many use cases.

For more specific answers you would have to give more specific details of your service and your scenario. But if you are at the early stages and still have to make choices about how to proceed (this is what it sounds like), then these links should help get you started.